# Anaconda2: cannot import name md5

Tags: anaconda

I just did a clean install of anaconda2 and conda always throws this error:

```
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/niid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/niid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/niid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
 File "/home/niid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/niid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
     globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
   File "/home/niid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
     raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/niid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
      globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
   File "/home/niid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
      raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/niid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/home/niid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
     raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/niid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
     globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
   File "/home/niid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
      raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/niid/.bin/conda", line 11, in <module>
      sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/niid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 182, in main
      return conda_exception_handler(_main, *args)
  File "/home/niid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 644, in conda_exception_handler
      return handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/niid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 634, in handle_exception print_unexpected_error_message(e)
  File "/home/niid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 596, in print_unexpected_error_message
    stderrlogger.info(get_main_info_str(get_info_dict()))
  File "/home/niid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_info.py", line 162, in get_info_dict
    from ..connection import user_agent
  File "/home/niid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/connection.py", line 12, in <module>
     from requests import Session, __version__ as REQUESTS_VERSION
  File "/home/niid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "/home/niid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/home/niid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .connection import (
  File "/home/niid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 39, in <module>
     from .util.ssl_ import (
  File "/home/niid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  from .ssl_ import (
    File "/home/niid/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 7, in <module>
  from hashlib import md5, sha1, sha256
ImportError: cannot import name md5
```

The first instance of this error happens when conda is called during installation.

It can be reproduced by manually calling conda or by calling

```
$HOME/anaconda2/python -c "import md5"
```

I was unable to find any fixes related to this problem so far. It is very strange since I just did

```
 rm -rf $HOME/anaconda2
```

and then did a clean reinstall.

**EDIT:**

The problem seems to be only with Anaconda 5. I reinstalled Anaconda 4.4.0 and the problem does not occur. I will try the anaconda forums.

Comment: Have you tried downloading a fresh copy? I think the installer checks for file integrity during install but I would also manually check the file hash of the installer and make sure you have file integrity.  Hashes here. `https://repo.continuum.io/archive/`.

Comment: Yes, I downloaded a fresh copy from the repo. Both Anaconda and Miniconda throw the same error.

Comment: Very strange.  I'm out of ideas right now but perhaps it would be helpful to post the OS & Version.

Comment: I am using WSL Ubuntu 14.04. But the problem seems to be known already: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6435

Comment: Thank you for your post. Anaconda2 v5 wasn't working for me either on WSL. However, Anaconda3 v5 is working.

Comment: That is odd. For me both do not work, but anaconda 4.4.0 works with python2 and 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the exact same problem, I believe Anaconda got it fixed in their latest release 25 Oct 2017 ([Anaconda 5.0.1](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/release-notes#anaconda-5-0-1-oct-25-2017)).

Now it worked for me.

https://www.anaconda.com/download/#linux

Comment: Yep. I recently checked to see if it was fixed and it works for me now too. Came here to give the update but you beat me to it Juno! :)